# I am trying to plot area vs volume

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am writing a lab report in chemistry discussing the surface of catalysts. I want to show that area doesn't increase proportionally to volume. I have been trying to plot a function vs against another function (e.g. volume vs. area). I am using a sphere as an example.

The volume of the sphere is: (4*pi*(radius)^3)/3

The area of a sphere is: 4 *pi * (radius)^2

I am trying to get a curve like that one (sphere):

[image]

I would like to use radii from 0 to 10 (continuously). I would greatly appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
plot? 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Like this ? `\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=1:10,no marks,xlabel=$V$,ylabel=$A$,grid=both]
\addplot ({(4*pi*(x)^3)/3},{4 *pi * (x)^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 3):

You can draw almost any arbitrary functional expression in the coordinate expressions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[domain=1:10,no marks,xlabel=$V$,ylabel=$A$,grid=both]
 \addplot ({(4*pi*(x)^3)/3},{4 *pi * (x)^2});
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```